# multiple horizontal bar charts to display in same row

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am using vue chart js with chart js 2.9.4 plugging and created 4 horizontal bar chars. All of them are currently displayed one after the another in different rows. How can I show them all in same row.

```html
    <ul v-for="(data, index) in deliveriesChartDatasets" style="display:inline">
      <li>
      <HorizontalBarChart
        :datasets="data"
        :show-legend="true"
      />
      </li>
    </ul>
```

As in above if I render this it will show 4 graphs row wise. But I need to show all of the 4 graphs in same line. Is there any way to change the width of the graph or do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-for` and `style="display:inline"` should be on the `<li>`, not the `<ul>`. Otherwise, each chart would be rendered in its own `<ul>`, which has a default `display:block` style, rendering the charts on their own line.

```html
<!--
<ul v-for="(data, index) in deliveriesChartDatasets" style="display:inline">
  <li>
-->

<ul>
  <li v-for="(data, index) in deliveriesChartDatasets" style="display:inline">
```

Also, a [`styles` binding](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-dynamic-styles) is needed on the `HorizontalBarChart` to set its `display:inline-block` and `width`:

```html
<HorizontalBarChart :styles="barStyles">
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      barStyles: {
        width: '200px',
        position: 'relative',
        display: 'inline-block',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/show-bar-charts-inline-midug?file=/src/App.vue)